# PHP - Notification upon email reciept using CPanel scripts

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I am helping re-code a website that allows teachers to text message/email their students about upcoming new/assignments.  Students can subscribe to their teacher's notifications by texting/emailing a flag to the inbox.

How would I go about watching these inbox's for incoming messages, to then flag php procedures (using cpanel scripts to interact with the email system)?

**If any more information is needed from me to make this more clear, please post.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle incoming emails using PHP you will need to "pipe" the emails to a script.

- [Email Piping with Cpanel](http://www.activecampaign.com/support/tt/kb/index.php?action=article&id=331)
- [Simple Email Logger Using cPanel’s Pipe Forwarder](http://www.devtrench.com/simple-email-logger-using-cpanels-pipe-forwarder/)

But, if you are specifically wanting to manage a Newsletter/Mailing List, then you may also want to look at something like [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/) as you may need to satisfy legal requirements for handling OptIn/OptOut, etc. actions.